# Building opencv with cmake error

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake

I am trying to build opencv with cmake and am running into issues.

I have downloaded the Windows opencv 2.3.1 to `C:/Users/chris/opencv`.  I open up the CMake GUI (2.8.5 version of CMake) and put the source directory as `C:/Users/chris/opencv/modules` and the "Where to build the binaries" at `C:/temp/opencv_binaries`

I hit `Configure` and chose Visual Studio 2010.  I then hit `Configure` again and get the following error output:

```
CMake Error at calib3d/CMakeLists.txt:1 (define_opencv_module):
  Unknown CMake command "define_opencv_module".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What gives?  What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless it has changed recently, the source directory should be `C:/Users/chris/opencv/` - it will be the highest-level directory with a CMakeLists.txt file in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

To turn `-Wno-dev` on you just need to select `Options` -> `Suppress dev Warnings (-Wno-dev)` in the menu of CMake GUI.

Answer (score 0):

what is the content of your CMakeLists.txt file?

for avoiding the warning, insert "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)" into the first line of your CMakeLists.txt